# USB ports didn't power off after shutdown in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, shutdown

I'm using Windows 10 Pro in my Dell Inspiron 3547 laptop. The issue is my USB ports remain powered after shutdown. It was never an issue until I upgraded to Win 10, and now I can't figure out how to make it stop.

I tried by configuring BIOS, updating the OS, and a few other ways.

Answer (score 2):

This "fast startup" seems to be a new feature in some recent Windows 10 update (I didn't have the problem with earlier versions of Windows 10).

Turning this off solved the problem for me (no need to change anything else, i.e. I still have selective suspension enabled and did not have to do any BIOS changes).

1. Go to `Windows > Settings > System > Power & sleep > Additional power settings > Choose what the power buttons do > Change settings that are currently unavailable`
2. **Uncheck** `Turn on fast startup (recommended)`
3. `Save changes`

Comment: This did not change it for me. I have an audio interface that remains lit up even after I disable fast startup. Do you have any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things I found something in my BIOS setup (HP Envy) which asks if I want USBs to be able to charge devices (phones etc,) after shutdown. I disabled it and the problem is solved. My battery no longer runs down overnight.

Answer (score 0):

From https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/usb-ports-remain-powered-after-shutdown/5a97d8d6-49d7-4537-a76d-7bb219aeb8d1:

> I think this is not an hardware issue, it's an OS setting. You don't
>   need to make BIOS changes. I think you can solve this in 2 steps:
>
> 1. Go to Control Panel > Power Options > Change Settings Scheme > Change Advanced Power Settings > USB Settings > and deactivate
>      Selective Suspension;
> 2. Go to Control Panel > Power Options > Choose What Power Buttons Do > Activate Settings Currentlly Unavailable > scroll down to Shutdown Settings > disable Activate Fast Start.
>
> That should solve your problem. It did for me ;-)

Comment: I followed above steps. But didn't work it.